# Java - '\' not being used to escape double quotes " in string

Tags: java, string, bytebuffer

I have some JSON content in bytebuffer as : {\"ID\":101}"}

This content is being returned from a service invocation. I get result from that microservice in a bytebuffer. (This means  - I cannot get the content changed)

Now, I need to get the json object from this buffer. I'm using this code :

```
            ByteBuffer payloadByteBuffer = invokeResult.getPayload();
            byte[] payloadByteArray = payloadByteBuffer.array();
            rawJson = new String(payloadByteArray, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            System.out.println("Raw JSon result = "+rawJson);
```

The string that gets printed is : "{\"ID\":101}"

Please note that '\' is getting printed within the string but it is originally used to escape double quote. So, when I try to convert this string to JSON object, I get an error :

"Missing value at 1 [character 2 line 1]"

which is probably due to '\' not being used to escape double quote character(I think).

So, My question is, how do I modify my string to treat '\' character for it's correct purpose?

I have tried replacing "\". but it didn't work. I don't know why.
I have also tried different charset encoding : US-ASCII and ASCII but got the same result.

Comment: `So, when I try to convert this string to JSON object` ... please show us the code where you use the string with the escaped double quotes.

Comment: shouldn't that String **print** as  `{"ID":101}` to be valid JSON?

Comment: This is not JSON

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I'm using this statement to convert string to JSON :

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(rawJson);

Comment: @Carlos: I want it to be printed as {"ID":101} but I don't know why "/" is being added

Comment: @lakshay apparently, the payload contains invalid JSON

Comment: @Maurice : The value getting returned as payload appears to be invalid to me too but, the service creates a json object as newJSONObject() and then converts it to a string and I get this string as the payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `json-simple`. You can use the dependency from [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple/1.1.1)

**P.S:** Your `JSON` response is wrong.

```
ByteBuffer payloadByteBuffer = invokeResult.getPayload();
byte[] payloadByteArray = payloadByteBuffer.array();
rawJson = new String(payloadByteArray, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
try {
        JSONObject json = (JSONObject) parser.parse(rawJson);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It parses the `JSON` with **\** in it.

Comment: Thanks, JSONParser seems to be working for me. Regarding JSON response, the service returns JSON object as a string. I think I will get it to return as json object instead of string

Comment: Even if the `JSONObject` is returned as a `String` it shouldn't make the `JSON` wrong. I guess the conversion from `JSONObject` to `String` is not proper. Up vote the answer if you liked.

Comment: I agree with you.. the issue is somewhere in JSON to string conversion. I am using jsonObject.toString() to convert json to string

Comment: You can make use of `Gson` library for converting `JSON` to `String`

Answer (score 0):

How about using the apache's commons lang library?

I think it's a simple and easy way of remove your problem away.

Here is my full test code for you.

```
package just.test;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.ibm.icu.impl.ByteBuffer;

public class UnescapeCharTest {

    private static void testJSONString(final String rawJson)
    {
        JSONObject json = null;

        try
        {
            json = new JSONObject(rawJson);
            System.out.println("ID = "+json.get("ID"));
        }
        catch(org.json.JSONException je)
        {
            je.printStackTrace();
        }

        String convJson = rawJson.replace("\\", "");

        try
        {
            json = new JSONObject(convJson);
            System.out.println("ID = "+json.get("ID"));
        }
        catch(org.json.JSONException je)
        {
            je.printStackTrace();
        }

        convJson = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJson(rawJson);

        try
        {
            json = new JSONObject(convJson);
            System.out.println("ID = "+json.get("ID"));
        }
        catch(org.json.JSONException je)
        {
            je.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        String rawJson = "{\\\"ID\\\":101}";

        testJSONString(rawJson);

        String rawJson2 = null;


        ByteBuffer payloadByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(rawJson.getBytes());

        byte[] payloadByteArray = payloadByteBuffer.array();
        rawJson2 = new String(payloadByteArray, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        testJSONString(rawJson2);


    }
}
```

I hope the code is right for you.

Have a good coding...

Comment: Thanks for your response .My code fails as soon as this statement is run 
     json = new JSONObject(rawJson);

Comment: What  is  your error  message? Do you  have proper jars in your classparh?